# Stacked text effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, typography

I'm searching for a tutorial explaining this effect 
[image]

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Can you tell us something more about your efforts? Have you searched for *typography portrait* tutorials? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23804827/word-portraits-visualization

Comment: There's a signature at the bottom. At least search for the artist if nothing else.

Comment: 1. I have searched, but could not find anything so random-spreaded as this one. 2. And how will the artist's name help me besides seeing the rest of his work ? I need to know how to do it, not how to see more of it.

Comment: I remember doing a project just like this in school. It's more of a typography exercise, not really a style or effect. If it had a name, I'd call it "Making a face with letter forms."

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's an automated effect. I think someone typed out some letters and arranged them in such a way that they created the shapes and shadows you see above.

Answer (score 2):

That's elementary, if you are a competent painter. With nonexistent painting skills you will struggle (except if you find a piece of automatic software that makes it for you) But finally you will get it by trial and error.

Painting:

Many graphic programs have symbol spray brush, which spray selected shapes instead of paint. The "nozzle" has several adjustments, which affect the width, density and randomness of the flow. You can add masking shapes which cover part of the sprayed shapes and some solid lines can be drawn, too. In your example there's black and white solid lines. The shading is made with texts and random letters.

An example(Inkscape)

[image]

Some symbols were sprayed along a drawn line with wide symbol spray brush. Then a white opaque shape was added. It covers  all just sprayed letters  to the right from the line. More letters were sprayed with reduced flow.

I bet all texts are in your example placed manually. They happen to fit too well to the needed lines. Also individual letters can be inserted one by one.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell you definitively how this one was done, however... there are some scripts out there which will arrange / distribute selected items along paths, and others which can then orient selected items towards another selected item.

http://shspage.blogspot.com.es/2014/02/distributeonthepathjsx.html
http://shspage.blogspot.com/2014/02/rotatetowardpointjsx.html

If you:

1. blow all text to outlines
2. separate individual letterforms in some cases, and words or phrases in others (pathfinder>union)
3. draw a loose vector portrait
4. then use these scripts

I'd bet you can get a good 2/3 of the way there in short order, then you can carefully manipulate the results to get the æsthetic effect you desire.